# unable to create softlink in sites-enabled in nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have deleted **default** and **default.save** files from both **sites-available** and **sites-enabled**. Then I created **node-app** in sites-available directory. Now I am writing 
**sudo ls -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/node-app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/node-app**  to create link to **sites-enabled** folder, but somehow I am getting the following error:

**ls: cannot access /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/node-app: No such file or directory
4 /etc/nginx/sites-available/node-app**

How can I point node-app file successfully?

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: yes.file exists

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cd sites-enabled
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/foo.conf .
ls -l
```

instead of

```
sudo ls -s /etc/nginx/site
```